# how to control the numbers of characters (numerics) with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to control the numbers of characters in an input field using jquery ...
ive got some control already but, i dont know what else to do ....

```
var foo = function(){
    if($('#foo1').val() == ''){
        $('.foo_foo_c').load('../html/message_error_number.html');
    }else{
        $('.foo_foo_c').load('../html/foo_foo.html',function(){
            listaStyle();
            listaPagadasStyle();
            listaDetalleLlamadasStyle();
        });
    }


};
```

Comment: please, format your code

Answer (score 1):

Look at using the jQuery [validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin and set up [maxLength](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/maxlength#length) or [rangeLength](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/rangelength#range) rule in addition to requiring that it be a [number](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like the [Alphanumeric](http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/) plugin.